# UIView change background transparency

Tags: iphone, objective-c, background, transparency

I am working on an Iphone Application.

I am creating a UIView:

```
UIView *popupView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 250, 250)];
```

Then I want to use an image as a background for the view:

```
UIColor * bgColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"blue_bg.png"]];

popupView.backgroundColor = bgColor;
```

Is there a way I can make that background semi transparent? maybe set the alfa value to 0.5 or give it an opacity.

I tried to make the image transparent using photoshop but when I set it as a background it is no longer transparent.

Note that I need only the background to be transparent not the subviews

Thanks a lot for any help

Comment: How to set the alpha? thanks

Comment: I thought you did know how to set it :-) Indler's answer came fast.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a simple trick for this. Add a subview of same frame and change it's alpha.

```
UIView *popupView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 250, 250)];
UIView *bgView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:popupView.frame];
UIColor * bgColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"blue_bg.png"]];
bgView.backgroundColor = bgColor;
bgView.alpha = 0.5;
[popupView addSubview:bgView];
```

Comment: +1, i was thinking for the same answer but got notification :(

Answer (score 1):

You can reduce alpha to 0.5 to make it transparent or change it as you required.

You can refer this[LINK](http://ios.biomsoft.com/tag/popup/)